# Trouble digital signing a driver on Windows 8/10

Tags: windows, driver, digital-signature, signing, signtool

My company sells a device that uses the 'usbser.sys' driver.
Up to Windows 7 we provided unsigned INF file, starting from Windows 8 we bought a DigiCert certificate to sign the driver.

**Trouble 1:**

- on Windows 8 the driver is installed and works fine, but on the device properties window (like this [example](http://cyberware.com/guides/cyscan/images/usb7_04_Properties.gif)) it says "Not digitally signed"

**Trouble 2:**

- on Windows 10, same problem as Windows 8, and also on some PCs our INF file is not automatically used on device connection, but the user has to manually select the INF file

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Can u mention the steps u did for signing the drivers?

Comment: I am using signtool ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx ). Something like: "signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword MyFile.exe"

Comment: After signing binaries using SignTool, can u just check the digital signature of your binaries whatever you have signed? Is it showing your certificate name there or not?

Comment: Yes, file seems to be correctly signed. also because you can't install not signed driver on Windows 10.

Comment: First thing u can install unsigned drivers on win10 also in test mode(installs with warning). It creates problem for 64 bit, there won't be able to install drivers at all unless test mode is on. Now coming to main point, how are u installing drivers on target PC?

Comment: I know about test mode, but it is not a solution for us, we need to deliver solid apps to our customers. We are installing drivers running dpinst tool in the same folder of INF files.

Comment: Yes you do, at installation does the OS show any warning?